# Python エラー

Tags: python

Pythonで写真のコードを書いたのですが、エラーになって動きません。
わかる方原因、対処法教えてください。

[image]

Comment: コードは画像としてではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けてみてください。

Comment: 原因は画像右側に表示されている通りです。(`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object ...` の部分) 対処は、、、コードを眺める限り、これは Twitter の OAuth 認証を Twitter 以外のウェブサイトの認証に利用するものかと思います。その点を誤解されている様です。

Answer (score 1):

BeatifulSoupでの要素の取得に失敗している（取得しようとしている要素が見つからない）のが原因でしょう。

１．解析対象のhtml(response.text)にそもそもその要素が存在しているのか？
２．要素の指定方法が間違っていないか？

を確認しましょう。